# Quickly won't package my app (11.10)

Tags: quickly

As the title suggests, I haven't been able to package my app with Quickly on Ubuntu 11.10. Here's the output

```
phoenix87@nestofheliopolis:~/Programming/python/gtumbler$ quickly package 
........
----------------------------------
Command returned some ERRORS:
----------------------------------
ERROR: Python module generic not found
ERROR: Python module utils not found
ERROR: Python module filters not found
ERROR: Python module xmp not found
ERROR: Python module System not found
ERROR: Python module pdf not found
----------------------------------
Command returned some WARNINGS:
----------------------------------
(setup.py:10740): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
WARNING: the following files are not recognized by DistUtilsExtra.auto:
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/HEAD
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/config
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/description
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/hooks/applypatch-msg.sample
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/hooks/commit-msg.sample
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/hooks/post-commit.sample
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/hooks/post-receive.sample
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/hooks/post-update.sample
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/hooks/pre-applypatch.sample
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/hooks/pre-commit.sample
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/hooks/pre-rebase.sample
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/hooks/update.sample
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/index
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/info/exclude
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/logs/HEAD
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/logs/refs/heads/trunk
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/objects/pack/pack-71084b8190f9a925d45b9689fb6b81332c525583.idx
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/objects/pack/pack-71084b8190f9a925d45b9689fb6b81332c525583.pack
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/packed-refs
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/refs/heads/trunk
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
----------------------------------
Do you want to continue (this is not safe!)? y/[n]: y
Ubuntu packaging created in debian/
.......................................................................
----------------------------------
Command returned some ERRORS:
----------------------------------
ERROR: Python module generic not found
ERROR: Python module utils not found
ERROR: Python module filters not found
ERROR: Python module xmp not found
ERROR: Python module System not found
ERROR: Python module pdf not found
----------------------------------
Command returned some WARNINGS:
----------------------------------
(setup.py:10965): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
WARNING: the following files are not recognized by DistUtilsExtra.auto:
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/HEAD
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/config
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/description
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/hooks/applypatch-msg.sample
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/hooks/commit-msg.sample
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/hooks/post-commit.sample
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/hooks/post-receive.sample
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/hooks/post-update.sample
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/hooks/pre-applypatch.sample
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/hooks/pre-commit.sample
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/hooks/pre-rebase.sample
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/hooks/update.sample
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/index
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/info/exclude
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/logs/HEAD
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/logs/refs/heads/trunk
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/objects/pack/pack-71084b8190f9a925d45b9689fb6b81332c525583.idx
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/objects/pack/pack-71084b8190f9a925d45b9689fb6b81332c525583.pack
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/packed-refs
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/refs/heads/trunk
  gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
----------------------------------
An error has occurred during package building
ERROR: package command failed
Aborting
```

Also how can I get rid of all (or at least most of) those unrecognized files?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Turned out that removing the folder gtumbler_lib/pdf.edited/ solved the problem. But I don't know where that folder came from in the first place. I need to investigate this further. Thank you anyway.